# SSL - self signed certificate with wildcard

Tags: ssl, certificate, wildcard, self-signed

I have created a certificate with CN: *.hostname

Chome & IE are complaining about this certificate when i'm navigating to dev.hostname or tst.hostname:

**Error in Chrome: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID**

Yes, I have added the certificate in my trusted root CA...

Should i add a domain like .local or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think most browsers don't allow wildcard at the second level, because usually a single entity does not own a top level domain. So you need to have something like `*.foo.local` instead of `*.foo`.